# Getting error in console - AngularJS - boilerplate not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap, boilerplate, angular-upgrade

I am using AngularJS boilerplate https://github.com/jbutko/AngularJS-Boilerplate with:

- AngularJS v1.3.20
- angular-sanitize 1.6
- angular-ui-bootstrap 2.1.4

I am trying to use bootstrap ui of angular. In console, I'm facing this issue

> **b.resolve is not a function**

Found some resolutions to update the angular to 1.4

When trying to update it, I'm getting the following error:

```
D:\projects\Bosst web\boost_v1>bower install angular#1.4 --save -F
bower invalid-meta  for:D:\projects\Bosst web\boost_v1\bower.json
bower invalid-meta  The "name" is recommended to be lowercase, can contain digit
s, dots, dashes
bower cached        https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.14
bower validate      1.4.14 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#
1.4
bower ENOTFOUND     Package AngularJS Boilerplate=angularjs-boilerplate not foun
d
```

> bower ENOTFOUND     Package AngularJS> Boilerplate=angularjs-boilerplate not found

Comment: I found the solutions of it, so closing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's version issue. Check your version